# Device not getting detected in DDMS in Ubuntu 12.04 - 32bit

Tags: android, adb, android-debug

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 32bit. I have a Micromax Ninja A87 Android phone running GB 2.3.5.
My problem is the phone does not get detected. When I try on a windows 7 pc, it does get detected.

Here are all the steps I followed but still no lucks.

```
$ lsusb
Output: Bus 002 Device 006: ID 1c9e:9e08 OMEGA TECHNOLOGY
```

I created the `51-android.rules` file and have this as the contents:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1c9e", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Alternatively I tried this link also - http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1475740

Done chmod a+r on 51-android.rules

Restarted udev , also restarted my PC.
done kill-server & start-server 
But still when I do "adb devices" -- it doesn't detect my phone.

Here are some more info:
1)USB debugging is enable in phone.
2)Whenever i connect my phone to pc, it shows a popup in PC("usbmodem mass storage has been connected").

Comment: does your ubuntu have proper drivers ti support the device connected?

Comment: I hope so, but still need to be confirmed. Can you let me know how can I check that ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/130285/my-android-phone-isnt-being-detected-by-ubuntu. If you don't find answer ask a question in askubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

while checking the vendorId and productId in windows(phone always detected by windows system), it shows 1c9e:9e18. But as mentioned, in ubuntu it shows 1c9e:9e08. So tried to switch to the same vendorId/productId in ubuntu i.e 1c9e:9e18. So created a rule in /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/1c9e:9e08 and put the below contents in the file. 
Code:

```
DefaultVendor=0x1c9e
DefaultProduct=0x9e08

TargetVendor=0x1c9e
TargetProduct=0x9e18

SierraMode=1
NoDriverLoading=1
```

add below code to the file /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules

```
ATTR{idVendor}="1c9e", ATTR{idProduct}="9e08", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
```

Once done run :

```
sudo usb_modeswitch -v 0x1c9e -p 0x9e08 -S -R -W
```

Now adb will recognise the phone.

For further reference you can go through the below link:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1968465

Comment: Please summarise the link in your answer; that way, if the link goes stale the answer won't be completely useless.

Comment: I switched the same device to 1c9e:9e18, but ```adb``` still does not recognize it.